# select parent row where ALL children rows meet criterias

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table, **rates** and **criterias**. parent_id in **criterias** refers to id in **rates**.
I need to select the rates where **ALL** children rows in table criterias WHERE criteria_1 AND criteria_2 equal to NULL. 
In the example below, only flat rate should be selected

rates

```
id   |    name   
--------------------
1    |    summer rate        
2    |    flat rate        
3    |    student rate
```

conditions

```
id   |   parent_id   |    criteria_1   |   criteria_2
------------------------------------------------------
1    |    1          |    523          |   563
2    |    1          |    null         |   null
3    |    2          |    null         |   null
4    |    2          |    null         |   null
5    |    3          |    777          |   null
```

I tried NOT EXIST, but it return it return any rate where one children have two null criteria

Comment: You say you tried not exists but we cannot see that

Answer (score 0):

I would use some aggregate function with an `having` clause grouped by `parent_id`.

Using a `min` or `max` would return a numerical value if there is at least one non-null value per `parent_id` but will be `null` if there are only `null`. So just need to use an `having min(<field>) is null` to find a `parent_id` with only `null` value.

```
select * 
from rates r
where id in(
    select parent_id
    from criterias
    group by parent_id
    having min(criteria_1) is null 
    and min(criteria_2) is null
);
```

or With an inner join (if you prefer)

```
select * 
from rates r
inner join (
    select parent_id
    from criterias
    group by parent_id
    having min(criteria_1) is null 
    and min(criteria_2) is null
) c ON c.parent_id = r.id;
```

Validated with :

```
create table rates(
    id int,
    name varchar(20)
);

create table criterias (
    id int,
    parent_id int,
    criteria_1 int null,
    criteria_2 int null
);

insert into rates values (1, 'summer rate');
insert into rates values (2, 'flate rate');
insert into rates values (3, 'student rate');
insert into rates values (4, 'old rate');
insert into rates values (5, 'any rate');

insert into criterias values (1, 1, 523, 563);
insert into criterias values (2, 1, null, null);
insert into criterias values (3, 2, null, null);
insert into criterias values (4, 2, null, null);
insert into criterias values (5, 1, 777, null);
insert into criterias values (6, 4, null, null);
insert into criterias values (7, 5, null, null);
insert into criterias values (8, 5, null, null);
/*insert into criterias values (9, 5, 1, null);*/

select * 
from rates r
where id in(
    select parent_id
    from criterias
    group by parent_id
    having min(criteria_1) is null 
    and min(criteria_2) is null
);
```

Result:

```
id  name
2   flate rate
4   old rate
5   any rate
```

Comment: Both queries return all parents the moment ONE child row have criteria_1 and criteria_2 equal to NULL

Comment: @user1709251 My bad, didn't catch the bold part ... this would do the trick

Comment: @user1709251 updated. The validation script show a commented line, adding that line will remove the `any rate` from the result.

Answer (score 0):

try using this `subquery` with `inner join`.

```
select * from 
    (select * from rates where name = 'flat rate') t1
inner join 
    (select * from criterias where coalesce(criteria_1, 0) = 0 and coalesce(criteria_2, 0) = 0) t2
            on t2.parent_id = t1.id
```

Comment: Is there any advantage using sub-queries like this ? Isn't it cleaner to put the condition in the `where` clause ? Note that this could (and will) return duplicates `rates` where the `criterias` were not required.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following query it should work. You need to compare 2 result set to find rate with ALL null childrens.

```
SELECT
a.parent_id
FROM(
SELECT
  parent_id,
  COUNT(*) AS total_count
FROM criterias c
WHERE c. criteria_1 IS NULL AND c.criteria_2 IS NULL
GROUP BY 1
) a
INNER JOIN (
SELECT
  parent_id,
  COUNT(*) AS total_count
FROM criterias c
GROUP BY 1
)b ON a.parent_id = b.parent_id AND a.total_count = b.total_count
```